# Is it possible to decrypt gzip information?

Tags: json, gzip, fiddler, unzip

I am using Fiddler on Google and I noticed that a content type json is arriving as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2011 22:55:56 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: gws
Content-Length: 317
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

--some big big big big encoded stuff here...--
```

So the question is: can I use some tool or create some code to **unzip** this result and see what is inside of `--some big big big big encoded stuff here...--`?

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but have you tried gzip? Notably gzcat on the binary payload?

Comment: You could also remove the "Accept-Encoding: gzip" client header, so the server replies with plain text instead of compressed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can click on the request on the left panel, then choose on Fiddler right bottom panel, click on *Transformer* tab, uncheck *Chunked Transfer-Encoding* and click *No Compression*.

[image]

Then click on *Raw* tab.

[image]